# Rails 3.2.11 deploy Heroku error

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, web-deployment, cedar

I got the application uploaded to heroku, during the uploading process, it did not show any sign of errors.

Yet, when I "heroku open" it, the only thing that rendered on the page is "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

So I just post the heroku logs here.

What's interesting is that the exact set of code runs on my local machine flawlessly.

This baffled me, tried for two days and stuck on this, please help.

```
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/home/index host=warm-beach-3817.herokuapp.com fwd=221.127.133.168 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=138ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3392054954454753443__process_action__93841041959637154__callbacks'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__854204767247210329__call__2389741480887842989__callbacks'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2013-01-28T15:43:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
```

**The Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "friendly_id"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'kaminari'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'haml-rails'
end
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced issues before with using

```
gem "therubyracer"
```

and deploying to heroku.

I found the solution was to switch to from

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

to

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
```

removing the requirement for therubyracer gem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works the same except you have to use scss for CSS rather than less